# Is there a prop.-logic formula $P$ s.t. $\forall x(\phi(x)\lor\psi(x))\iff P(\forall x\phi(x),\exists x\phi(x), \forall x\psi(x),\exists x\psi(x))$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I could prove (hopefully correctly) that
$$
\forall x (\varphi(x) \land \psi(x)) \equiv \forall x \varphi(x) \land \forall x \psi(x)
$$
($\forall$ distributes over $\land$), and
$$
\forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x)) \vdash \forall x \varphi(x) \lor \exists x \psi(x)
$$
which is just an implication but not an equivalence, since it is not symmetric in $\varphi$ and $\psi$, as it should be.

The idea is to write an equivalent of $\forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x))$ in terms of $\forall x \varphi(x), \exists x \varphi(x), \forall x \psi(x)$ and $ \exists x \psi(x)$ connected *only* by logical connectors $\land,\lor,\to,\neg$. In other words: is there a propositional logic formula $P$ such that
$$
\forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x) ) \equiv P(\forall x \varphi(x), \exists x \varphi(x), \forall x \psi(x),\exists x \psi(x))
$$
?

**My Attempt:** I thought about symmetrising the implied formula above as
$$
[\forall x \varphi(x) \lor \exists x \psi(x)] \lor 
[\forall x \psi(x) \lor \exists x \varphi(x)]
$$
since this may weaken the implication, [lol](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E6x(Px%7E2Qx)%7E4(((%7E6xPx)%7E2(%7E7xQx))%7E2((%7E6xQx)%7E2(%7E7xPx)))).

Comment: I assume you mean P has to be one of the 16 binary gates.  So 2 bits of input.  There's no way to encode enough information about $\varphi$ and $\psi$ into 2 bits to say whether their overlap is total.  I don't know how to say that formally though, hopefully someone else can put it more formally in an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge in logic is quite limited and can't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: In Wiki they don't mention above in the page that $\psi$ (there) has no free $x$, which is strange. My idea is find the relation between a quantifier on a non-atomic formula (a disjunction) and a formula consisting of quantifiers on the atomic formulas composing the former formula

Comment: Hint: Case 1: $A,B$ are proper non-empty subsets of the universe $U$ whose union is $U$. Case 2: $A,B$ are proper non-empty subsets of the universe $U$ whose union is not all of $U$. The left hand side comes out T in case 1 but F in case 2, but both parameter lists on the right side are $(F,T,F,T)$. So no such propositional formula can work in both cases. (sorry I don't know how to format greek letters, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, second try, similar idea, same conclusion (there's no such function $P$):

Suppose the language has two constant symbols $c_1$ and $c_2$. Let $$\varphi(x)=(x=c_1),$$ $$\psi(x)=(x=c_2),$$ $$A = \forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x)),$$ $$B = P(\forall x \varphi(x), \exists x \varphi(x), \forall x \psi(x),\exists x \psi(x))$$

If $P(F,T,F,T)=F$ then, in a model with exactly two elements, $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

If $P(F,T,F,T)=T$ then, in a model with more than two elements, $A$ is false and $B$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such function $P$: If the language has one constant symbol $c$ and a model has at least two elements, let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be defined as follows:

If $Q=\forall$ and $P(F,F) = T$: $\varphi(x)= \psi(x)=\neg(x=x)$.

If $Q=\forall$ and $P(F,F) = F$: $\varphi(x)= (x=c)$ and $\psi(x)=\neg(x=c)$.

If $Q=\exists$ and $P(T,T) = T$: $\varphi(x)= \psi(x)=(x=c)$.

If $Q=\exists$ and $P(T,T) = F$: $\varphi(x)= \psi(x)=(x=x)$.

In each of the cases above the truth value of $\forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x))$ is different from the truth value of $P(Q x \varphi(x), Q x \psi(x))$, so they can't be equivalent.

Comment: I think I had to clarify something about $P$, it has four arguments not just two. I said in the post: *" in terms of ..."*.

Comment: See my second answer